# How can I get the Element Id from XML parse in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, arrays, xml, google-apps-script

Xml Code

```
<directory>
 <fieldset>
  <field id="displayName">Display name</field>
  
 </fieldset>
 <employees>
  <employee id="123">
   <field id="displayName">John Doe</field>
   
  </employee>
  <employee id="160">
   <field id="displayName">Jane Doe</field>
   
  </employee>
```

I can parse the information with XmlService.parse and get the value within each element, but I cannot get the employee/element id number

When I run this:

```
var roots = document.getRootElement().getChild('employees').getChildren();
```

I get the individual elements but I cannot get the id's

```
 [[Element: <employee/>], [Element: <employee/>], [Element: <employee/>], [Element: <employee/>], [Element: <employee/>], [Element: <employee/>], [Element: <employee/>], [Element: <employee/>], [Element: <employee/>], [Element: <employee/>], [Element: <employee/>], [Element: <employee/>], [Element: <employee/>], [Element: <employee/>], [Element: <employee/>], [Element: <employee/>], [Element: <employee/>], [Element: <employee/>], [Element: <employee/>], [Element: <employee/>], [Element: <employee/>], [Element: <employee/>], [Element: <employee/>], [Element: <employee/>], [Element: <employee/>], [Element: <employee/>], [Element: <employee/>], [Element: <employee/>], [Element: <employee/>], [Element: <employee/>], [Element: <employee/>], [Element: <employee/>], [Element: <employee/>], [Element: <employee/>], [Element: <employee/>], [Element: <employee/>], [Element: <employee/>], [Element: <employee/>]]
```

Answer (score 2):

- You want to retrieve `123` and `160` from the following xml data.

  ```
    <directory>
      <fieldset>
        <field id="displayName">Display name</field>
      </fieldset>
      <employees>
        <employee id="123">
          <field id="displayName">John Doe</field>
        </employee>
        <employee id="160">
          <field id="displayName">Jane Doe</field>
        </employee>
  ```
- You want to achieve this using XmlService of Google Apps Script.

#### Modification point:

- In your case, `roots` retrieves `employee`. So using this, you can retrieve the attribute of `id`.

#### Modified script:

When above xml data is used, the sample script is as follows. In this sample, `</employees></directory>` is added to the sample xml data.

```
function myFunction() {
  const xml = `<directory>
  <fieldset>
    <field id="displayName">Display name</field>
  </fieldset>
  <employees>
    <employee id="123">
      <field id="displayName">John Doe</field>
    </employee>
    <employee id="160">
      <field id="displayName">Jane Doe</field>
    </employee>
  </employees>
</directory>`;
  var document = XmlService.parse(xml);
  var roots = document.getRootElement().getChild('employees').getChildren();
  var ids = roots.map(e => e.getAttribute("id").getValue());
  console.log(ids);  // [123, 160]
}
```

#### Note:

- In this case, please use the script with V8.
- If you want to retrieve both `id` of `employee` and the value of `field`, you can also use the following script.

  ```
    var ids = roots.map(e => ({id: e.getAttribute("id").getValue(), name: e.getChild("field").getText()}));
  ```

  - In this case, `[ { id: '123', name: 'John Doe' }, { id: '160', name: 'Jane Doe' } ]` is retrieved.
- **When the structure of above xml sample data is different from your actual data, the modified script might not work. So please be careful this.**

#### Reference:

- [getAttribute(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/element#getAttribute(String))

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function() {
   var roots =document.getElementsByTagName("employees")[0].children;
   
   for(k=0;k<roots.length;k++){
    var id=roots[k].getAttribute("id")
    console.log(id);
   
   }
   
   

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<directory>
 <fieldset>
  <field id="displayName">Display name</field>
 </fieldset>
 <employees>
  <employee id="123">
   <field id="displayName">John Doe</field>
  </employee>
  <employee id="160">
   <field id="displayName">Jane Doe</field>
  </employee>
  </employees>
 </directory>
```

you can access id like this using javascript