# How to write Google App Script XML response to Google Sheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, xml-parsing

I have a short script to pull from an API and write one field from the response to a Google Sheet. Here is my code:

```
function getData() {
  var output = [];

  // modified from https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/
  var url = "https://api.bamboohr.com/api/gateway.php/XXXXXX/v1/employees/directory";
  var apiKey = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
  var authHeader = "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(apiKey + ":x");  
  var xml = UrlFetchApp.fetch( url, {"headers":{"TRN-Api-Key": apiKey, "Authorization": authHeader}}).getContentText(); 
  var document = XmlService.parse(xml); // parse

  // next nav to part of tree and get values
  var roots = document.getRootElement().getChild('employees').getChild('employee').getElementById('firstName');
  var ids = roots.map(e => e.getAttribute("id").getValue());

  output.push([roots]);
  

  // where we want it to go
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11CYFiP_AXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, output.length, 1).setValues(output);
}
```

Here is what the XML response looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<directory>
 </fieldset>
 <employees>
  <employee id="40923">
   <field id="firstName">Peter</field>
```

How can I return the firstName field for all entries? (i.e. the first column of my spreadsheet will read "Peter", then "Joe", etc.

Comment: Is your question related to this question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/63286188/7108653 If it's so, how about using `var ids = roots.map(e => ({id: e.getAttribute("id").getValue(), name: e.getChild("field").getText()}));` instead of `var ids = roots.map(e => e.getAttribute("id").getValue());` like the answer?

Comment: My request is unrelated to that one, but they are probably trying to pull from the same API given the similarities in the field names. When I ran `var ids = roots.map(e => e.getAttribute("id").getValue())` only the first entry was returned (Peter), but no others.

Comment: [Edit] your question to show why it's not a duplicate with your updated code and logging details(eg: log of `console.log(ids)`) and why the question be reopened. See [mcve]

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your case, I think that the information for replicating your issue is required to confirm your issue as @TheMaster 's comment. By the way, although I'm not sure whether this is useful for your situation, when `var res = document.getRootElement().getChild('employees').getChildren().map(e => ({id: e.getAttribute("id").getValue(), name: e.getChild("field").getText()}));` is used, what result will you get?